# How to run testcafe using saucelabs tunnels

Tags: testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe, saucelabs

I want to run my testcafe scripts using saucelabs tunnel. I tried searching the documentation for doing the same but didn't find any.

I tried searching the documentation on the testcafe github, saucelabs documentations. Saucelabs documentation primarily for selenium.

If anyone successfully configured testcafe with saucelabs tunnel please share the steps.

Answer (score 1):

If you follow steps described at the [Run Tests on Sauce Labs with Travis CI](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/continuous-integration/travis-and-sauce-labs.html) article, you will not require any additional configuration. The browser provider that you install on the step 4 will do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

See [Run Tests on Sauce Labs with Travis CI](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/continuous-integration/travis-and-sauce-labs.html)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This document does not have information about configuring tunnels.